# Apache error on Centos7 / Plesk - AH01068: Got bogus

Tags: mysql, apache, nginx, centos7, plesk

My site has been struggling since yesterday. I checked the logs and here are the errors in the apache log.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69x5O.png)

At the same time, I have a mysql process that uses a lot of cpu resources (sometimes up to 900).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Nje5.png)

When I kill this process, everything returns to normal....and then starts again.

Do you have any idea where this might be coming from?
I haven't made any recent changes to my site.

Centos7 Apache with FPM application served by nginx and Plesk

I have kill the procee, restared the server..then it slows again

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an Apache2 `mod_proxy_fcgi` bug that was fixed a long time ago:

This is Apache bug 49671, which has been fixed in Apache version 2.4.16.

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56110
https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49671

**Just upgrade Apache2 to a newer version**.

Comment: I use apache version 2.4.6-98.el7.centos.7

Comment: You should use Apache version 2.4.16. Pay attention to the miner version.